# Django "TemplateView" and "/media/" url conflict

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am writing an SPA with Django 1.11 (switching to 2.0 is no an option), as backend, getting all the data from Django Rest Framework API and I route my app via React routing.

Here is my my main **urls.py** :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include('text_cms.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('photos_admin.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'),
    ]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And here is my **settings.py** file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media-files/'
```

The issue is, that the particular url setting

`url('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'),`

is messing up media url, and files uploaded by user cannot be reached by url link, even though they are saved to folder, I just get a 404 error. When I comment my "Template as view" url, delete it or just give it another address, like **url('main/')** - everything works fine again.

I've tried to serve the template from the other app and registering it in the main urls.py file, but it did not work too

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.IndexView),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def IndexView(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {})
```

Comment: How is it messing up? Are you getting any errors? I'm pretty sure your home url should be `'/'` and not just `''`.

Comment: I just get a 404 error, whenever I try ro reach my media file.
Everything else works just fine.
'/' instead of '' did not help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'),
```

You are missing a closing ). It also appears that you url pattern is incorrect as well. Should be

```
url(r'^$' , TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

Comment: Thank you, that eventually helped to solve my issue!
P.S.  I missed a closing ) only here, while I was deleting irrelevant urls, in the project file it was on it's place. Anyway, the root of the issue was this regular expression. Thank you very much indeed!